# After NSLayoutConstraint changed, systemLayoutSizeFittingSize is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using Autolayout on swift and I want to change `UIImageView` height of `UICollectionViewCell` dynamically.

I tried like following.
but, it seems like that `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is not working.

```
class CellImage: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeight:NSLayoutConstraint!
     .
     .
     .
    internal func setup() {
        self.imageHeight.constant = 200
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
     .
     .
     .
    class func sizeForRow(#collectionView: UICollectionView, content: Content) -> CGSize {
        var cell = UINib(nibName:"name", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! CellImage
        let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)
        cell.frame.size.width = width
        cell.setup()
        let height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return CGSizeMake(width, height) // not correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
let height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
```

With  below code

```
let height =cell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)
```